# ¿Como mover el contenido del div al medio de una imagen del carousel?

Tags: php, jquery, css, html5, bootstrap-carousel

Muy buenas querido amigos!, necesito que me ayuden que un div que dentro lleva datos ponerlo en una imagen (item de carousel) centrado.
imagen de referencia...[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel text-center">
    <?php
    require_once("config.php");
    $posts=$db->query("select * from posts order by id");
    $contador=0;
    if ($filas=$posts->fetch_array())
    {
        do
        {
            $contador++;
        ?>
        <div class="item">
            <img class="lazyOwl" src="images/gallery-<?php echo $contador;?>.jpg" alt="Tout dé Cake">
        <h3><?php echo utf8_encode($filas["plato"]);?></h3>
        <ul class="votos">
            <li class="voting_btn up_button" data-voto="likes" data-id="<?php echo $filas["id"]; ?>"><span><?php echo $filas["likes"]; ?></span></li>
            <li class="voting_btn dw_button" data-voto="hates" data-id="<?php echo $filas["id"]; ?>"><span><?php echo $filas["hates"]; ?></span></li>
        </ul>
        </div>

        <?php
        }
        while($filas=$posts->fetch_array());
    }
    else echo "<h3>No hay entradas disponibles.</h3>";
    ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Pasa el codigo que estes usando para que tu respuesta sea bien recibida

Comment: Es la misma pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/127647/como-poner-el-titulo-y-los-votos-en-cada-item-del-carousel

Comment: es distinta, quise separar de una pregunta a otra... bueno me podrian ayudar. mover ese div al medio de la imagen :D

Comment: Y como te ayudo si no posteas codigo? Mira [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Ahi lo tienes amigazo! ojala me puedas ayudar :D

Comment: Me referia al html, css, javascript, jquery ´porque uno no puede correr el ejemplo hecho a php, porque recuerda PHP es del lado del servidor, consulta tablas que uno no conoce. Tienes que subir un [Ejemplo minimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: pero solo es utilizar css, no tiene  nada que ver con otra cosa, bueno dejalo ahi amigo veo que no hay ayuda aqui...

Comment: No es eso amigo, solo que de que me sirve decirte que pruebes a darle un margin-top: 50% ?? porque probaras y luego vendras diciendo que no funciono. Entonces con un ejemplo verificable no perderemos el tiempo. Es mi humilde opinion. Ojala encuentres quien te pueda ayudar solo con mostrarle la foto.

Comment: No es que no haya ayuda @DannyHO es que los foros tienen sus reglas y una de esas es lo que sugiere Luis Fernando, si quieres recibir ayuda gratuita lo mínimo que puedes hacer es tratar de cumplir las reglas, si alguien te da una respuesta y esta no se acomoda a lo que necesitas, va a ser preciso por eso mismo que no especificaste, que por algo existirán no? ;) Éxitos y feliz año!

Answer (score 1):

Buenas.

Todo el secreto está en CSS. Suponiendo que tu html sea algo parecido a esto:

```
<div class="soyElFondo">
  <div class="soyElFormulario">
    <fieldset>
      <span>T&iacute;tulo</span><br>
      <ul>
      <li>Contenido</li>
      <li>M&aacute;s contenido</li>
      </ul>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

Atención a los valores en el atributo **class**, porque de ellos depende que las propiedades de CSS se apliquen a donde corresponde, así:

```
.soyElFondo {
   background-image: tu_imagen.png /* apuntando a la imagen que deseas */
   width: 800px;
   height: 800px;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

.soyElFormulario {
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
}
```

En [este link](https://jsfiddle.net/fcsbmadn/) puedes verlo funcionando. Un saludo...

... actualizo mi respuesta, porque no presté atención al 100% a la pregunta (el pequeño gran detalle de PHP). Coloca el atributo de estilo background-image por php.

```
...
<div class="item soyElFondo" style="background-image: images/gallery-<?php echo $contador;?>.jpg">
    <div class="votos soyElFormulario">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

El resto de mi propuesta va igual, ahora sí.
Otro saludo.

Answer (score 0):

hay mas en Bootstrap que pocos saben. Generalmente el css de Bootstrap pisa cualquier orden dada desde un estilo propio. En el carrusel de hay una opsion para poder comentario a las imagenes

```
<div class="item">
<img src="..." alt="...">
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h3>...</h3>
<p>...</p>
</div>
</div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#carousel

Si deseas modificar algo que ya viene por defectos, tienes que crear una hoja de estilo propia y a cada opcion terminarla con **!important**.

ejemplo:

```
.margin-top: 10px !important;
```

Espero haberte ayudado. Saludos!